# Significance of certain folders in linux kernel tree

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

While going through [Linux Kernel Source tree](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.10/), found certain folders, explanation of which was not seen in the popular sites. Could someone tell why these folders are there like:

- block - This is not the block folder in the driver directory
- security
- sound
- tools
- usr
- virt

Comment: If you browse into those folders, and read the Kconfig and other files, you can work out what they're for.  For example, /virt appears to contain the kvm kernel stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some basic descriptions of these directories.

- `block` - This contains code for the kernel block layer. It's the generic block code. The drivers in `drivers/block` are device-specific.
- `security` - Code for [apparmor](http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/Main_Page), [selinux](http://selinuxproject.org/page/Main_Page), [securityfs](http://lwn.net/Articles/153366/), [capabilities](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/security/linux-privs/kernel-2.2/capfaq-0.2.txt), etc.
- `sound` - Code for sound. The [ALSA](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page) code lives here.
- `tools` - Tools for testing, information generation, data dumps, etc. This toolset is separate from the kernel. It contains a bunch of little tools. None of the code under `tools` is built into the kernel. It's its own little sub-project of sorts.
- `usr` - There's a utility for generating an [initial CPIO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd) here.
- `virt` - [KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page)-specific code